# Asymptotics for the number of abelian groups of order at most $x.$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, gr.group-theory, analytic-number-theory

The number of abelian groups of order $n$ (call it $a(n)$ is a studied subject (see http://oeis.org/A000688), but I can't seem to find any asymptotic results. Obviously, there is no asymptotic for $a(n)$ itself (it is much too irregular), but there should an asymptotic for $\sum_{n\leq x} a(n),$ but I can't seem to find a reference.

Roberto answered the above, but another question is whether one has any distributional results (how high are the maxima, is there a limiting distribution, etc).

Comment: Out of curiosity, would there be a nice formula for counting abelian groups $G$ with coefficient $1/|{\rm Aut}(G)|$?

Comment: @LevBorisov Well, the first question along this line is: given $\Prod C_{p^{k_i}},$ for $p$ some prime, what is the order of the automorphism group? I am sure this is in the literature somewhere...

Comment: re the automorphism group, there is a recent-ish Monthly paper on this, the preprint is http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605185

Comment: @quid that's a great reference, thanks!

Comment: @LevBorisov If you look at quid's reference, the first lemma tells us (I believe)  that the number of groups mod automorphism is again a multiplicative function of $n,$ so there should be nice asymptotics, but I think the summatory function should grow like $\log n.$

Comment: One complicating factor, when discussing automorphisms, is that the automorphism group depends of course on the repetitions of $p^k$ among the primary components of the group. This means that there probably won't be as simple a generating function that records $p$-groups weighted by automorphisms, the way $\prod_{k=1}^\infty (1-p^{-ks})^{-1})$ is the generating function that records $p$-groups themselves.

Comment: @GregMartin true, but I think there is enough information to get the asymptotic (for square fee numbers, you basically get the sum of $1/n,$ which makes the logarithmic estimate plausible).

Comment: Order of magnitude, certainly, probably both upper and lower bounds. Might be tough to get the exact leading constant though.

Comment: @GregMartin Agreed, though the formula is explicit enough to hope for the best. The deeper philosophical question is what the significance of modding out by the automorphism group is...

Comment: @GregMartin Actually, if you look carefully at theorem 4.1 in quid's reference, it seems that the automorphism group is MUCH larger than linear in $n$ for $n=p^k,$ so I am guessing that the asymptotic result is that Lev's sum is $6\log x/\pi^2 + O(1).$

Comment: In practice, that's not how these convergent series work. We've agreed, I think, that Lev's sum restricted to squarefree numbers is asymptotically $\frac6{\pi^2}\log x$. Are you proposing that Lev's sum restricted to $4$ times odd squarefree numbers, for example, is $O(1)$?

Comment: @GregMartin Fair point, I withdraw my previous estimate, but keep my opinion that the constant is computable :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem was studied quite a bit; a complete summary will be complicated to give (in any case I cannot). A standard reference for classical results on this is **A. Ivić "The Riemann Zeta-function: Theory and Applications"** (1985); it seems there is a recent Dover edition. Ivić has various papers on this problem, too. The book has a chapter on this subject (14.5 Non-isomorphic abelian groups of a given order). At the moment I cannot recall what exactly is in there.

**Some information related to this type of problem:**

The correct asymptotics for $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}} a(n)$ were obtained by 
Erdős and Szekeres (1934), they proved: 
$$\sum_{n\le x} a(n) \sim A x + O(\sqrt{x})$$
with $A= \prod_{n \ge 2}\zeta(n)$.

By now there are more precise results known. For example  the paper by Kendall and Rankin (1947), mentioned in another answer, gives $Ax + B x^{1/2} + O(x^{1/3} \log x )$, and developments continued, like the result mentioned by Roberto Pignatelli.

The to my knowledge latest improvement there is by Sargos and Wu (2000)
$$Ax + Bx^{1/2} + Cx^{1/3} + O(x^{55/219} (\log x)^7 )$$
The first to get the third term of the main term was Richert (1952). 
For the historical development of the error see the introduction of a paper by  Calderón (2003).

Related questions were also studied. For example,  Kendall and Rankin (1947) showed that the "local densities" of $a(n)$ exist, that is   $\sum_{n \le x, \, a(n)=k}1 \sim d_k x$ (good error terms are known). 
There are also estimates "in short intervals" so on $\sum_{ x \le n \le y, \, a(n)=k}1$.

For two recent papers on this see:

*Emre Alkan*, [**On the enumeration of finite abelian and solvable groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0022-314X(03)00055-6), *J. Number Theory* **101** (2003), no. 2, 404--423.

*Ekkehard Krätzel*, [**The distribution of values of the enumerating function of finite, non-isomorphic abelian groups in short intervals**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00013-008-2732-7), *Arch. Math. (Basel)* **91** (2008), no. 6, 518--525.

The introductions and references there will lead to various additional paper. (The first is freely accessible.)

*References*

C. Calderón:  Asymptotic estimates on finite abelian groups. Publications De L’institut Mathematique, Nouvelle série, 74, 57-70 (2003).

P. Erdős, G. Szekeres: Über die Anzahl der Abelschen Gruppen gegebener Ordnung und über ein verwandtes zahlentheoretisches Problem (in German), Acta Litt. Sci. Szeged 7 (1934), 95--102; Zentralblatt 10,294. [Free PDF](https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1934-05.pdf)

*D. G. Kendall and R. A. Rankin*, [**On the number of Abelian groups of a given order**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=22569), *Quart. J. Math., Oxford Ser.* **18** (1947), 197--208.

*Hans-Egon Richert*, [**Über die Anzahl Abelscher Gruppen gegebener Ordnung. I**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=50577), *Math. Z.* **56** (1952), 21--32.

*P. Sargos and J. Wu*, [**Multiple exponential sums with monomials and their applications in number theory**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1006777803163), *Acta Math. Hungar.* **87** (2000), no. 4, 333--354.

Comment: As I just read, apparently, there is a more recent result with $O(x^{1/4+\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon>0$: http://www.degruyter.com/dg/viewarticle/j$002fcrll.2006.2006.issue-591$002fcrelle.2006.012$002fcrelle.2006.012.xml !!!

Answer (score 7):

One reference where the asymptotic result you are asking for was first established (I think), as well as some reasonable growth estimates for $a_n$, is

D.G.Kendall and R.A.Rankin, "On the number of Abelian groups of a given order", Quart. J. Math., Oxford Ser. 18 (1947), 197–208.

(full text: http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/content/os-18/1/197.full.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelianGroup.html it is a theorem of Srinivasan (1973), click on the link for details.

Comment: There are earlier results giving asymptotics as far as I know thus to say "it is a theorem of Srinivasan (1973)" is a bit misleading.